# footnote reset in every page, Latex

Tags: latex

When using `\footnote{text}` in *TeXnicCenter Latex*, the number will reset in every new page. 
I want that the nummber associated with the footnote increment automatically in every chapter.

Comment: You may be better off asking this on http://tex.stackexchange.com. Also, please don't use a signature or tagline. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/

Answer (score 1):

It's largely dependent on the `\documentclass` you use.  Different document classes have different defaults, but you can use the [`chngcntr`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=running-nos) package, which provides the commands `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout`